Why is 'Service Host: WaaSMedicSvc' running as a subprocess of Google Chrome?
While looking through Task Manager on my Windows 11 PC, I noticed "Service Host: WaaSMedicSvc" was running as a subprocess of Google Chrome and using up 800 MB of memory. According to TheWindowsClub, WaaSMedicSvc is meant to be a Windows service for repairing Windows Update components. If that's true, why would WaaSMedicSvc be running as a subprocess of Google Chrome?

